# How to access global variables inside functions

Tags: function, crystal-lang

I have following simple code:

```
line = "Hello"

def myfn()
    puts line
end

myfn()
```

The variable `line` is not accessible in function. How can global variables be accessed inside functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it a constant via capitalization.

```
LINE = "Hello"

def myfn()
    puts LINE
end

myfn()
```

If you want it to be variable pass it in as an argument, that's what they're for.

```
line = "Hello"

def myfn(msg)
    puts msg
end

myfn(line)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can [create a module with a class variable if you need a 'global' state](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/710l).

```rb
module Foo
  extend self

  @@line = "Hello"

  def myfn
    puts @@line
  end
end

Foo.myfn
```

Comment: Good information. Should this code be in a file named Foo.cr or can filename be any?

Comment: The filename is not really relevant for the _compiler_. But it would be indeed a good style to call it `foo.cr`.

Comment: What does @@ stand for? Global variable? What is its scope?

Comment: @rnso it means it is a class variable. Which means you don't need to call Foo.new to access it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an alternative solution:

```
line = "Hello"

myfn = ->() {
  puts line
}

myfn.call
```

Comment: Interesting! Is there any name for this syntax?

Comment: A few names: Procs (specific in  Crystal), closures, lambda or anonymous functions (in general programming).